# Buttons not visible in the Layout Editor of Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android-studio

Although many tutorials, videos, and books in Internet show the `baseline edit`. `delete constraint` and `cycle chain mode`  buttons (`x`, `ab` and `chain`buttons) below the selected component in the Layout Editor, I can't see them in my updated *Android Studio 3.4*.  How is it possible? I can only do these operations with the context menu.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, I've installed Android Studio 3.4.1 on Linux
```
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-1038-oem
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find menu to toggle Baseline from context menu e.g

> Activity Design View > Component Tree

[image: Activity Design View > Component Tree]

> Select button2 and right-click to bring up the Context menu on button2

[image: Right click button2]

Comment: I know the functionality of the 3 buttons ( baseline edit,. delete constraint and cycle chain mode) can be obtained in another way. However, the question relates to why I cannot see the 3 buttons below the view.

Comment: The question was about the 3 buttons below views. I also know about the context menu already.

Comment: @nyxee I would love to see your answer with a screenshot , thanks

Answer (score 3):

They have updated and move the option to the [right click menu](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#baseline)

You have to right click your `TextView` component and show baseline
[image]